# Identify all items in a list which exist more than once and list them all

Tags: powershell

I have a list in which several items are repeated. I need to identify those items and create a new list to include all the repeated items, but for every time they reoccur.

Here's the list:

```
apple
orange
pear
carrot
tomato
cucumber
apple
apple
apple
cucumber
tomato
```

Thats apple x4, tomato x2, cucumber x2 and the rest x1.

The desired new list would be:

```
apple
apple
apple
apple
tomato
tomato
cucumber
cucumber
```

This omits the ones that exist only once and lists the ones that exist more than once and every time they occur.

I have tried:

```
$Fruits = Get-Content -Path C:\temp\Fruits.txt

$Unique = $Fruits | Select-Object -Unique
$MoreThanOne = Compare-Object –referenceobject $Unique –differenceobject $Fruits | Select-Object -ExpandProperty inputobject

$MoreThanOne
```

This produces:

```
apple
apple
apple
cucumber
tomato
```

Which is one missing for each fruit.

Any thoughts please?

Comment: Thanks! $Fruits | group | ? Count -gt 1 | % Group works!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By Comparing the both Objects and saving the difference you basically do a `($Unique - "each entry once")`. This is because you want the difference between the variable which holds all entries and the variable which holds each entry once.

A better solution to this offers `Group-Object`. This groups all entries together so that you can look out for the one with multiple entries.

The Command `Get-Content -Path C:\temp\Fruits.txt | Group-Object` outputs this:

```
Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
    4 apple                     {apple, apple, apple, apple}
    2 tomato                    {tomato, tomato}
    2 cucumber                  {cucumber, cucumber}
    1 carrot                    {carrot}
    1 pear                      {pear}
    1 orange                    {orange}
```

If you now filter correct:

```
Get-Content -Path C:\temp\Fruits.txt | Group-Object | Where-Object {$_.Count -gt 1} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Group
```

The Output is this:

```
apple
apple
apple
apple
tomato
tomato
cucumber
cucumber
```